# Expresión regular, fórmula con paréntesis. Moodle question type preg

Tags: python, regex, matemáticas, moodle

He instalado en Moodle un tipo de pregunta llamado "preg", que es capaz de reconocer expresiones regulares. El caso es que he planteado un ejercicio en el que los alumnos tienen que escribir la siguiente instrucción en Python:

> Escribe exactamente la sentencia que se describe: si "i" al cuadrado más "j" al cuadrado es igual (igual de comparación) a "k" al cuadrado  dos puntos.

Evidentemente la respuesta es: `if (i**2+j**2==k**2):` , pero también es posible sin paréntesis `if i**2+j**2==k**2:`

No he encontrado una solución para este problema. Esta expresión `if\s+((i\*{2}2\s*\+\s*j\*{2}2\s*==\s*k\*{2}2)|\(\2\))\s*:` no me funciona y no sé por qué. Evidentemente `if i**2+j**2==k**2):` o `if (i**2+j**2==k**2:` no son soluciones válidas.

NOTA: el alumno puede introducir algunos espacios entre la fórmula. Se lo permito.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo lo que pretendías hacer, pero no puede funcionar. Tu expresión regular:

```
if\s+((i\*{2}2\s*\+\s*j\*{2}2\s*==\s*k\*{2}2)|\(\2\))\s*:
```

Básicamente se lee así:

- Encaja la palabra `if`  seguida de uno o más espacios, y después:

  1. O bien el texto `i**2+j*+2==k**2` con espacios opcionales en ciertos lugares
  2. O bien lo que haya encajado en el punto anterior rodeado de paréntesis.
- Y luego espacios opcionales y dos puntos.

La clave es *lo que haya encajado en el punto anterior*. Si el usuario no usa paréntesis, eso encaja con el punto 1. y no necesita mirar el 2. Pero si el usuario utiliza paréntesis, entonces *no encaja nada con el punto 1* (ya que ese punto no admite paréntesis alrededor de la expresión) por lo que `\2` estará vacío, y tampoco encajará la segunda parte.

Lo que tú buscabas es algo como:

- Sea `\E` la expresión `i\*{2}2\s*\+\s*j\*{2}2\s*==\s*k\*{2}2`
- La expresión regular sería `if\s+(\E|\(\E\))\s*:`

Pero por desgracia no hay forma de "definir" expresiones regulares que puedan ser usadas más adelante dentro de la expresión. Si te das cuenta, en el fondo lo que buscas es una especie de "context free grammar" que tenga reglas de producción, o reglas BNF. Y las expresiones regulares no son tan potentes.

Naturalmente puedes marcar como "opcional" los paréntesis de apertura y cierre, haciendo algo como `\(? ... \)?`, pero  eso dejaría pasar soluciones en las que se abre el paréntesis pero no se cierra, o viceversa, las cuales queremos evitar.

Se me ocurre otra forma de lograr lo que buscas, y es hacer uso de un "condicional" *if-then-else* dentro de la expresión regular, que eso sí que está soportado (aunque no sé si lo soportará el plugin de Moodle que estás usando).

La idea de una expresión condicional *if-then-else* en regexp es esta:

```
(a)?(?(1)b|c)
```

Donde `(a)` sería un grupo de captura que al llevar un interrogante detrás sería condicional, mientras que la parte  `(?(1)b|c)` sería el *if-then-else* del cual se usará la parte `b`  (*then*) si el grupo de captura `1` no está vacío o la parte `c` (*else*) si estaba vacío. La condición por tanto en este ejemplo, es la existencia o no de contenido en el grupo `(a)`.

Mi idea entonces es capturar el paréntesis de apertura, y usarlo en la expresión *if-then-else* para detectar el de cierre (si habíamos encontrado el de apertura), o una cadena vacía (si no). Es decir:

```
if\s+(\()?i\*{2}2\s*\+\s*j\*{2}2\s*==\s*k\*{2}2(?(1)\)|)\s*:
```

Demo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/X1PxFa/2)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora no tengo tiempo de probarlo, pero tiene buena pinta.

Comment: Gracias. Funciona bien en Moodle. :-)

Comment: @AurelioGallardoRodríguez Me alegra comprobarlo. La sintaxis _if-then-else_ de las expresiones regulares no está soportada en JavaScript, por lo que no las tenía todas conmigo, pero creo que Moodle está escrito en PHP que sí la soporta.